# How to check if graphics card driver is up to date?

Tags: graphics, graphic-card, amd-graphics

I have a fresh install of Linux Mint 17 xfce and I would like to check if the graphics card driver is up to date. I have a AMD radeon x1650 graphics card. How do I check if my graphics card driver is up to date?

Answer (score 1):

There are two potential ways to answer the question here.  Do you want to make sure you have the most up to date driver that is in your distribution's repositories, or are you looking for the most up to date version from AMD (which is usually newer than the distribution's repositories, as it takes time for the distribution to check and verify it works well with the OS in general, etc).

From a root terminal, you can run:

```
apt-get update
```

To update (or see all updates) for packages in your distribution.

If you want to see what version you have installed, you can run:

```
dpkg -l fglrx-driver
```

This will show you some output that will include the Version string.  You should be able to compare this to what AMD's website lists to see how much newer the version is from them.  Ignore the dash and anything after it.

Note as well that fglrx is AMD's non-free binary driver.

Comment: `apt-get update` will only update the list of available packages. It will not install anything and it will not show any updates. You need to run that _and_ `apt-get upgrade` to actually install any newer versions.

Comment: I received the following command suggested by Jim : dpkg-query: no packages found matching fglrx-driver